# How do export an eclipse product to Linux?

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-rcp, rcp, delta-pack

I tried to export to Linux (32 and 64 bits) an eclipse product with help of Delta Pack 4.2.2 and 4.3 but does not work and throws me the next error:

**Processing inclusion from feature org.eclipse.equinox.executable: 
Bundle org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.gtk.linux.x86_1.1.200.v20130521-0416 failed to resolve.:**

I tried to add manually the **"org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.gtk.linux.x86_1.1.200.v20130521-0416.jar"** but does not work.

I used **Eclipse Kepler, Build id: 20130919-0819**, and I don't found a delta pack for my Build id (20130919)

anyone can help me, please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can download the 4.3.1 delta pack from `http://download.eclipse.org/eclipse/downloads/drops4/R-4.3.1-201309111000/`. You do need to use the delta pack that matches your release.

Answer (score 2):

The correct and recommended way to add the libraries for the export to other target platforms this one:

This is works not only with the Mars release, but also previous releases, as well.

- Open Window/Preferences.
- Find PDE/Target Platform
- Select your (active) target platform
- Click Edit
- Click Add
- Select "Software Site"
- Click Next
- In "Work With" type: http://download.eclipse.org/eclipse/updates/4.3 (replace 4.3 with your current version)
- Check "Eclipse RCP Target Components"
- Check "Equinox Target Components"
- Uncheck "Include required software"
- Check "Include all environments"
- Press Finish
- Press Finish
- Press OK

Open your product file and select the "Export" option. You will see that the "Export for multiple platforms" checkbox is available.

This description was found on here: